# How do I SAFELY render Markdown from a React component?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I want to display markdown in my ReactJS app, but its important that it's done safely.  The markdown files I will be displaying are untrusted public content.

I've seen various solutions and they all use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

I can't help thinking that this might be, well, dangerous.

Anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[They gave `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` a scary name very deliberately](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), to make sure people would think *very* carefully about whether they needed to use it/whether they were using it correctly. Seeing as you're asking this question, clearly it's done that job pretty well! But Markdown rendering is in fact one instance where it's necessary.

Basically, what it comes down to is: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is only dangerous when you don't make sure the stuff you're putting into it is safe beforehand. Be careful, but don't be scared off by it!

**EDIT:** As mentioned by Waylan in the comments, the example I gave was pretty naive and didn't take into account [other ways XSS attacks can be achieved through Markdown](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/). Most likely you're going to want to run the *output* through a sanitizer instead of/as well as the input, otherwise it's very possible to generate malicious HTML without doing something as straightforward as just embedding a `script` tag. The main point of my answer remains the same though; `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is only as dangerous as what you put into it. Do your research, make sure the input is safe, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Escaping raw HTML is **not** sufficient to avoid XSS attacks in Markdown documents. See [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah, looking at the issues on [the Marked repo](https://github.com/chjj/marked/pull/592), it looks like the sanitize option doesn't handle stuff like that, you're right. I'll add a note to my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @Waylan: Updated my answer, thanks for letting me know there was problems with it!

Comment: "... only dangerous when you don't make sure the stuff you're putting into it is safe beforehand." That's good advice. If the Markdown source is always coming from a trusted source (you), then it is probably safe to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with no other precautions. Otherwise, you need to sanitize it as outlined. @JoeClay, glad I could help, +1 for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is not trusted (and you can't do anything about it) the library should sanitize the input properly before displaying it.

I have found two libraries that seem to do that:

- [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown/issues/55)

  Just make sure that `escapeHtml` option is set to `true`. To test, set "HTML mode" to "Escape" on [demo page](https://rexxars.github.io/react-markdown/).
- [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable/issues/67)

  Didn't test it, and safety is [not](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable/issues/67#issuecomment-60834375) "an explicitly stated goal of the project". The information is from 2014 though, so that might have changed (no info in README). YMMV.